# How to create models in sails.js that are using foreign key relations..?

Tags: model, sails.js, waterline

I am very new to sails and trying to create an app.
Here is the code to my model

```
// api/controllers/Friend.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        user: {
          model: "user",
        },

        friend: {
          model : "user",
        },
    },
};
```

and here is how I am trying to create a new Friend instance in my controllers..

```
Friend.create({
    user : req.user,
    friend: user.id // friend is a User obeject 
}, function(err, request) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Some Error occured");
        res.json(err);
    }
    else {
        res.json({message: "Request Sent.", reqeust : request});
    }
});
```

But when I do so.. an error comes up.. Its very messy and difficult to understand..

I hope I'd be doing something simply stupid.. How can I fix this..

Here are the contents of my package.json file if it helps..

```
  1 {
  2     "name": "testApp",
  3     "private": true,
  4     "version": "0.0.0",
  5     "description": "a Sails application",
  6     "dependencies": {
  7         "sails": "0.9.16",
  8         "grunt": "0.4.1",
  9         "sails-disk": "~0.9.0",
 10         "ejs": "0.8.4",
 11         "optimist": "0.3.4"
 12     },
 13     "scripts": {
 14         "start": "node app.js",
 15         "debug": "node debug app.js"
 16     },
 17     "main": "app.js",
 18     "repository": "",
 19     "author": "",
 20     "license": ""
 21 }
```